# how to zoom out on desktop with kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, zooming

My desktop some how got enlarged and everything I open is large. How do I make it smaller again?? I have kubuntu.I have looked in multiple areas and tried everything to make it normal again and nothing has helped.

Answer (score 1):

First check the resolution of KUbuntu Desktop .

Get output:

```
 xrandr -q
```

Set Resolutions:

```
 xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1024x768
```

If you are still getting issue try to update driver.